# Django Orm Query - Reverse list lookup

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Its easy to check if item is in a list via Django ORM like

User.objects.filter(name__in = ['x', 'y'])

how about reverse way. 
if User has a field say list of suburbs which he vists (A comma separated list)  and we have to check if he has not visited a particular suburb .

```
class User(models.Model):
    suburb = models.TextField(_('suburbs'),validators=[validate_comma_separated_integer_list], blank=True)
```

Data when retrieved from shell_plus will be of this sort for

```
{'suburb': '965,967,969,972' }
```

Want to get all users who have not visited suburb 100  ?

Comment: This is more a job for a search engine than a database; unless you structure your models correctly so that instead of a string, you have actual references to records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

```
startswith_string = str(suburb) + ","
contains_string = "," + str(suburb) + ","
endswith_string = "," + str(suburb)

users = User.objects.filter(
    Q(suburb__startswith=startswith_string) | Q(suburb__contains=contains_string) | Q(suburb__endswith=endswith_string),
)
```

Comment: This will include entries that contain the value 1100 also if it is present at the last :)

Comment: It won't. The entry should end with `,100` :) . Note the comma in the beginning of `endswith_string`.

Comment: I thought you were using contains in all Q ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`contains` lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-contains) like

```
User.objects.exclude(suburb__contains='100')
```

If you are using postgres db, then I will suggest you use [ArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) instead of comma seprated values.

Comment: This will exclude entries that contain the value 1000 also.

Comment: You are correct i.e. why I am suggesting him to use ArrayField.

Answer (score 0):

Try using exclude with [in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#in) lookup

```
User.objects.exclude(suburb__in=['100'])
```

If your input is {'suburb': '965,967,969,972'},

```
input = {'suburb': '965,967,969,972' }
input_list = input['suburb'].split(',') # Split the string into list
User.objects.exclude(suburb__in=input_list)
```